# python mysql type error

Tags: python, mysql, types

In python I am having trouble with the types in the following code:

```
>>> curRow = 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
>>> curCol = 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
>>> type(curRow)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
type 'int'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
>>> cur.execute("select COUNT(*) from adjacency where r = %d and c = %d", (curRow, curCol))                                                                                                                                                   
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 183, in execute                                                                                                                                                                    
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

Note `r` and `c` are both `int` fields in table `adjacency`

I am very confused as `curRow` and `curCol` are clearly of type `int`, and `%d` means give me an `int`. What is python confusing as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Because `.execute()` doesn't just do a `%` substitution of the arguments you pass it. It runs them through escaping first, which in the process turns the values into strings.

Use `%s` instead.

Comment: What you said seems to be working. Could you explain a little bit more though? In terms of programming, this seems not straightforward (I am used to Java). Does this mean everything is a string and we never have to worry about it?

Comment: `MySQLdb` runs every value you give for a substitution through a SQL-escaping function beforehand, to help prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). A by-product of this is that the escaping function always returns strings, so the value substituted into the query text is always a string, regardless of what was passed in.